# Fuerte for Debian Connection timed out

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm a newb with Linux and especially with ROS.

I doing a project to control iRobot Roomba with Raspberry Pi 2. I'm trying to install ROS fuerte and I'm following these guides: [guide1](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Fuerte%20on%20RaspberryPi) [guide2](http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Debian)

All goes well until I have to I have to install core libraries. Doesn't matter if I try the ROS-Full or ROS-Base, I get connection timeouts. Could it be that the link in the guide isn't up-to-date?

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall
rosinstall operating on /home/pi/ros-underlay from specifications in rosinstall files  http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing /home/pi/ros-underlay/.rosinstall
[actionlib] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-actionlib_1.8.7_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/actionlib
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/actionlib'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[catkin] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-catkin_0.4.5-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/catkin
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/catkin'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[common_msgs] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/common_msgs-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-common-msgs_1.8.13-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/common_msgs
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/common_msgs'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[gencpp] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/gencpp-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-gencpp_0.3.4-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/gencpp
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/gencpp'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[genlisp] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/genlisp-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-genlisp_0.3.3-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/genlisp
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/genlisp'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[genmsg] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/genmsg-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-genmsg_0.3.10-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/genmsg
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/genmsg'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[genpy] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/genpy-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-genpy_0.3.7-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/genpy
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/genpy'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[ros] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-ros_1.8.10-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/ros'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[ros_comm] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-ros-comm_1.8.15-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_comm
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_comm'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[ros_tutorials] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_tutorials-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-ros-tutorials_0.2.19-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[roscpp_core] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/roscpp_core-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-roscpp-core_0.2.6-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/roscpp_core
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/roscpp_core'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[rospack] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/rospack-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-rospack_2.0.13-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/rospack
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/rospack'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[std_msgs] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/std_msgs-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-std-msgs_0.4.11-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/std_msgs
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/std_msgs'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
[rx] Fetching git://github.com/ros-gbp/rx-release.git (version debian/ros-fuerte-rx_1.8.9-0_lucid) to /home/pi/ros-underlay/rx
Cloning into '/home/pi/ros-underlay/rx'...
fatal: read error: Connection timed out
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'actionlib' : [actionlib] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-actionlib_1.8.7_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/actionlib failed.
Error processing 'catkin' : [catkin] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-catkin_0.4.5-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/catkin failed.
Error processing 'common_msgs' : [common_msgs] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/common_msgs-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-common-msgs_1.8.13-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/common_msgs failed.
Error processing 'gencpp' : [gencpp] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/gencpp-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-gencpp_0.3.4-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/gencpp failed.
Error processing 'genlisp' : [genlisp] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/genlisp-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-genlisp_0.3.3-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/genlisp failed.
Error processing 'genmsg' : [genmsg] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/genmsg-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-genmsg_0.3.10-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/genmsg failed.
Error processing 'genpy' : [genpy] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/genpy-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-genpy_0.3.7-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/genpy failed.
Error processing 'ros' : [ros] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-ros_1.8.10-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros failed.
Error processing 'ros_comm' : [ros_comm] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-ros-comm_1.8.15-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_comm failed.
Error processing 'ros_tutorials' : [ros_tutorials] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_tutorials-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-ros-tutorials_0.2.19-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials failed.
Error processing 'roscpp_core' : [roscpp_core] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/roscpp_core-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-roscpp-core_0.2.6-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/roscpp_core failed.
Error processing 'rospack' : [rospack] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/rospack-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-rospack_2.0.13-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/rospack failed.
Error processing 'std_msgs' : [std_msgs] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/std_msgs-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-std-msgs_0.4.11-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/std_msgs failed.
Error processing 'rx' : [rx] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/rx-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-rx_1.8.9-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/rx failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'actionlib' : [actionlib] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-actionlib_1.8.7_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/actionlib failed.
Error processing 'catkin' : [catkin] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-catkin_0.4.5-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/catkin failed.
Error processing 'common_msgs' : [common_msgs] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/common_msgs-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-common-msgs_1.8.13-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/common_msgs failed.
Error processing 'gencpp' : [gencpp] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/gencpp-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-gencpp_0.3.4-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/gencpp failed.
Error processing 'genlisp' : [genlisp] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/genlisp-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-genlisp_0.3.3-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/genlisp failed.
Error processing 'genmsg' : [genmsg] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/genmsg-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-genmsg_0.3.10-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/genmsg failed.
Error processing 'genpy' : [genpy] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/genpy-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-genpy_0.3.7-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/genpy failed.
Error processing 'ros' : [ros] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-ros_1.8.10-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros failed.
Error processing 'ros_comm' : [ros_comm] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-ros-comm_1.8.15-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_comm failed.
Error processing 'ros_tutorials' : [ros_tutorials] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_tutorials-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-ros-tutorials_0.2.19-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials failed.
Error processing 'roscpp_core' : [roscpp_core] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/roscpp_core-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-roscpp-core_0.2.6-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/roscpp_core failed.
Error processing 'rospack' : [rospack] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/rospack-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-rospack_2.0.13-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/rospack failed.
Error processing 'std_msgs' : [std_msgs] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/std_msgs-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-std-msgs_0.4.11-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/std_msgs failed.
Error processing 'rx' : [rx] Checkout of git://github.com/ros-gbp/rx-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-rx_1.8.9-0_lucid into /home/pi/ros-underlay/rx failed.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220740/fuerte-for-debian-connection-timed-out/) by [DirtyWork](https://answers.ros.org/users/25067/dirtywork/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-11**:
Please don't use screenshots to show terminal text. If the imgur link ever goes down, this question becomes useless, so please copy/paste whatever is in the terminal into your question. Use the *edit* button/link, and format it using the *Preformatted text* button (with `101010` on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you behind a (corporate) firewall and / or proxy server? The errors tell you that connections to Github are timing out, but actual issues with their infrastructure are rather rare. Try changing all `git://` urls in the `.rosinstall` to `http://` (leave the rest). See if that works.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DirtyWork](https://answers.ros.org/users/25067/dirtywork/) on 2015-11-11**:
Thanks to [gvdhoorn](http://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/), I had to change `git://` to `http://` in `.rosinstall`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-12**:
So just for future readers: are you behind a proxy and / or firewall?

**Comment by [DirtyWork](https://answers.ros.org/users/25067/dirtywork/) on 2015-11-12**:
Sorry forgot to mention it. This is college network, I believe it's behind a firewall.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-12**:
Also: if at all possible, I wouldn't use such an old ROS distribution anymore. Fuerte is now almost 4 releases old, and has been EOL for a long time.